# Group by 3 columns and find max/min according to 4th?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to group by `col1` , `col2` and `col4` and find the max and min of each group according to `col3`

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7], 
     'col2': ['w', 'w','w','w','w','e','e','e','e','e','e','t','t','t','t','t'], 
     'col3': [ 1,4,1,1,2,3,5,8,2,3,3,5,3,3,4,3], #in every combination this decides the max or min
     'col4': [ 5,5,6,6,6,3,3,3,1,1,1,4,4,4,6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

produces this:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1   w   1   5  #1w5 is one group where by col3 has max 4 and min 1
1   1   w   4   5 #thus we make a col `max` with 4 and one `min` with 1
2   2   w   1   6
3   3   w   1   6
4   3   w   2   6
5   4   e   3   3
6   4   e   5   3
7   4   e   8   3
8   5   e   2   1
9   5   e   3   1
10  5   e   3   1
11  6   t   5   4
12  6   t   3   4
13  6   t   3   4
14  7   t   4   6
15  7   t   3   6
```

I tried this:

```
df.groupby('col1','col2','col4')['col3'].max()
```

returned this:

> ValueError: No axis named col2 for object type

Comment: Have you tried: `df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].max()` ?

Comment: yeah thanks. Can you suggest a way to do the new columns as it says in th question. I can't make a new column in the dataframe itself as `df['max'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].max()`.

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col4']).col3.transform('max')` to create a Series with the same initial index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a list of columns on which you want to process group by and define a name to new column

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].max().reset_index(name ='Max')
```

Output

```
col1    col2    col4    Max
1       w       5       4
2       w       6       1
3       w       6       2
4       e       3       8
5       e       1       3
6       t       4       5
7       t       6       4
```

Or to get the complete list use transform

```
df['Max']=df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    Max
1       w       1       5       4
1       w       4       5       4
2       w       1       6       1
3       w       1       6       2
3       w       2       6       2
4       e       3       3       8
4       e       5       3       8
4       e       8       3       8
5       e       2       1       3
5       e       3       1       3
5       e       3       1       3
6       t       5       4       5
6       t       3       4       5
6       t       3       4       5
7       t       4       6       4   
7       t       3       6       4
```

Comment: include how to delete rows where col3 is empty and you are good.